# UWP SQLite - Return null but data in table

Tags: sqlite, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have datain my database (shown in the screen)
[image: data]

But the returned values are `null`? How is that possible, in the output I got this:

[image: output]

This is the code I'm using:

```
public static SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("RPR_REKENSOFTWARE_DB.db");
public static List<String> GetParts()
        {
            var items = new List<String>();
            try
            {
                string sSQL = @"SELECT * FROM parts;";
                ISQLiteStatement dbState = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL);
                // Get the records
                while (dbState.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
                {
                    // Say what it is.
                    string partNr = dbState[1] as string;

                    items.Add(partNr);
                }
                return items;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This is the database I'm using:

[image: db structure]

Comment: I suspect the problem could be in XAML, could you post that part as well? And could you set a breakpoint on `return items;` line and check if the values returned are actually `null`?

Comment: The return value is null for sure (debugged it), the xaml is just a select box on which I set the itemsource. Beside that, I have simmelar code which works, I think it's really strang that this code doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are converting the value from database to `string`, although it is actually an `int`. You should do:

```
string partNr = ( ( int )dbState[ 1 ] ).ToString();
```

Or more simply:

```
string partNr = dbState[ 1 ].ToString();
```

The reason is that the row returned from database is contains .NET equivalents of the DB column types and hence `dbState[1]` is an `int`. When you use `as string` on an int however, it cannot be cast and you get `null`.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding :-)